# How to use notifyAll for a specific thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, eclipse, runnable

Okay so this is the code. It basically has three classes. One of them is increasing a value and the other one decreasing with an endless loop. But when the value goes over or under a specific limit, it has to stop. But since both of the functions have notifyAll, it wakes the other functions as well so even if it is at the limit, it keeps going. How can I solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

First Class (increasing and with Thread):

```
public class Producer extends Thread{

private Counter counter;

public Producer(Counter counter) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.counter=counter;
}


@Override
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //super.run();
    
    for(;;) {
        try {
            counter.increase();
            sleep(100);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            System.out.println("Producer:"+e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    
}
```

The second class (decreasing with Runnable):

```
public class Consumer implements Runnable{

private Counter counter;

public Consumer(Counter counter) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.counter=counter;
}


@Override
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //super.run();
    
    for(;;) {
        try {
            counter.decrease();
            
            Thread.currentThread().sleep(100);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            System.out.println("Consumer:"+e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    
}
```

}

Third class which contains the functions:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Counter {

private int counter;
private Random ran;

public Counter() {
    //super();
    counter=0;
    ran= new Random();
}



public synchronized void increase() {
    int number=ran.nextInt(5);
    
    if(counter+number>=100 ) {
    
        System.out.println("Producer is stopping, value is: "+counter);
        System.out.println("The generated number is: "+number);
        try {
            wait();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            System.out.println("error in increasing mehtod"+e.getMessage());
        }

    }
    
    counter = counter+number;
    notifyAll();
    System.out.println("Prdoucer increase: "+counter);
}


public synchronized void decrease() {
    int number= ran.nextInt(5);
    if(counter-number<0) {
        System.out.println("Consumer is stopping, value is: "+counter);
        System.out.println("The generated number is: "+number);
        try {
            wait();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            System.out.println("error in decreasing mehtod"+e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    counter = counter-number;
    notifyAll();
    System.out.println("Consumer decrease: "+counter);
    
 }



}
```

Comment: when you work with wait() and notifyAll(), the wait() method should be called in a loop and you should exit from there only when the condition is false, otherwise you should call wait again. You can try changing the if's from the increase and decrease methods to while and see if this solves your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Read about spurious notifies. A thread can be notified even without explicit call to notify()/notifyAll(). So after each notify the thread must check if it was indeed notified, and be ready to find out it was notified in vain.

Comment: You should add in your answer, that the common pattern is to use a `while` loop instead of an `if` statement when deciding to call `wait`.

Answer (score 1):

> .How to use `notifyAll()` for a specific thread.

You don't. That's not what `notifyAll()` is for, and it's not what `notify()` is for either.

You use `notify()` and/or `notifyAll()` to notify other threads that some particular thing has changed or happened. You use `notify()` when it's guaranteed that any single thread that catches the notification will be able to deal with whatever it was that changed or happened.  You use `notifyAll()` otherwise.

In neither case does the caller get to specify *which* thread or threads should be notified. The system will randomly chose any single thread that happens to be waiting in an `o.wait()` call if you call `o.notify()` for the same object `o`, or it will notify *all* of the threads that happen to be waiting in `o.wait()` if you call `o.notifyAll()`.  It won't do anything for threads that aren't already in an `o.wait()` call at the moment when `o.notify()` or `o.notifyAll()` was called.

It's up to you to write code that exploits those functions to your advantage. There's plenty of examples and tutorials out there for how to do that.  My personal favorite:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html

---

Also note: Correctly usage of `notify()` and `notifyAll()` is somewhat tricky. It's tricky for you to write it correctly, and it's tricky for other people who want to read and understand your code.

If you think you need `notify()` or `notifyAll()` the first thing you should do is consider whether or not you could use some higher-level class that encapsulates the notify/wait behavior.  E.g., for a "producer/consumer" architecture, you might consider using a [`BlockingQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html).